# ChartJs is not working in angular 4 with no errors

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-chart

I am being new to chart js ,trying to implement in angular 4 application.
even though no errors in the code chart is not appearing in browser. I referred a lot of documentation and online material to implement chart.i have spent almost 3 days to figure out the cause.Please help me to rectify the same 
thank you

```
Here is my code 
dependencies:
```

> "chart.js": "^2.7.3"

in angular cli.json

> "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",

in Component

> import {Chart} from 'chart.js';

```
ngOnInit() {
    const el = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('myChart');
    const ctx = el.getContext('2d');

    console.log(el);
    console.log(ctx);

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero:true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
  });

}
```

in html

```
 <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

I am getting no error in broswer and i am able to print both native element and context and Chart object as well .Not sure why chart is not appearing in browser.
Please help

```
nativeEliment on console giving-
<canvas _ngcontent-c1="" height="0" id="myChart" width="0" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; height: 0px; width: 0px;"></canvas>

context on console:
CanvasRenderingContext2D {canvas: canvas#myChart, globalAlpha: 1, globalCompositeOperation: "source-over", filter: "none", imageSmoothingEnabled: true, …}

chart object on console.log-Chart {id: 0, ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, canvas: canvas#myChart.chartjs-render-monitor, config: {…}, width: 0, …}
```

Comment: i don't know angular, but some few doubts. 1) is ngOnInit is the right method where it should call 2) the id and variable name are similar . Also please refer this article if you can find anything from this one https://coursetro.com/posts/code/126/Let's-build-an-Angular-5-Chart.js-App---Tutorial

Comment: You can use: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart or check there sources on github

Comment: Thank you for replying ...@DILEEP THOMAS and @ Marcel Hoekstra .I found a way to implement .i tried with ng2-charts/angular2-chartjs libraries and it worked for me with both of the libraries.As you suggested Primeng is also working for me .

Answer (score 2):

I got that the thread is somewhat outdated, however to spare other the nervs i've spend on the matter, i'll provide this:

**The canvas** (- *now* -) **has to be nested within a `display:block`-styled Element**

*Since i use angular (CLI) 8.0.3 and Chart.js v2.8.0, this might not solve your problem either.*

Nevertheless i also ran into serveral other problems you might consider at this point:
almost every other snippet i've found so far is kinda obsolete.
Check your @ViewChild Annotation as well as your Rx-imports, if they'r up to date (even if you won't got any compile errors)

Comment: you saved my day! almost 4 hours finding what's wrong in the configuration... Thanks a lot!